# Editing git commit in nonconflicting way from long ago results in conflicts

Tags: git, rebase, merge-conflict-resolution

We have some data that was accidentally stored in one of our configuration files and stuck in there unnoticed for about a month. It's a private repo with very limited user access, so we would like to rewrite history and pull that data out before sharing the repo with others.

The configuration file has not been changed since the undesirable commit, so I attempted

```
git rebase -i $parent_commit^
```

and chose to edit the appropriate commit. After continuing, it goes through about 30+ commits before hitting a merge conflict on an entirely unrelated file. I would have thought rebasing should work fine in this case since the config file has not been changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out rebase doesn't attempt merges by default, so after doing

```
rebase --preserve-merges -i $parent_commit^
```

I only hit a few errors where it for some reason couldn't merge some of the files. In this case, the output gave me the merge commit id, so doing

```
git checkout <merge_commit_id> -- file/that/is/conflicting
```

would get me to the state I wanted.